# Make the next elements stay fixed after hiding an element

Tags: jquery, html, css

suppose that we have three elements in an HTML file that one of them (the middle one; .div2) is hidden. I'm trying to unhide the hidden element (.div2) and hide the first element (.div1) by clicking on a button using jQuery. But the problem is when I hide the first element (.div1) and unhide the hidden element (.div2), the next element (third one; .div3) slides up and is mixed with the unhidden element.

What should I do to solve this?

```js
$(function($) {
  $(".myButton").click(function() {
    $(".div1").fadeOut();
    $(".div2").fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="myButton">Hide</button>
<div class="div1">Element 1 - will be hidden</div>
<div class="div2" style="display: none;">Element 2 - the hidden element</div>
<div class="div3">Element 3 - the one which will slide up and mess with element 2 </div>
```

The messed up result is as the image:
[The result after clicking the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEnvM.jpg)

As you see, there's a form field (element 2) behind a map (element 3), which I want the map stays at the bottom of the form field and not to slides up.

Comment: Show the CSS code for your DIVs.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri yes the problem was its style properties -_- . Fixed it by changing its height to "auto". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery CSS to hide the element instead. Better use opacity to hide/show and use CSS transitions for the effects.

Comment: Thank you. But another question. the height of div2 is different than div1 and so still some overlap exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback argument of `fadeOut` -- it is called when the animation is finished. That way, as soon as the first div is completely hidden, the second starts showing, so that there is always exactly one of them taking vertical space:

```js
$(function($) {
  $(".myButton").click(function() {
    $(".div1").fadeOut(function () {
       $(".div2").fadeIn(500);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="myButton">Hide</button>
<div class="div1">Element 1 - will be hidden</div>
<div class="div2" style="display: none;">Element 2 - the hidden element</div>
<div class="div3">Element 3 - the one which will slide up and mess with element 2 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` both are animated and you are using it at same time and at some point of animation they are becoming both `display:block`, thats why you are facing the issue...

So either use `hide()` instead of `fadeOut()` or just `fadeOut(0)`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(function($) {
  $(".myButton").click(function() {
    $(".div1").hide();
    // or $(".div1").fadeOut(0);
    $(".div2").fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="myButton">Hide</button>
<div class="div1">Element 1 - will be hidden</div>
<div class="div2" style="display: none;">Element 2 - the hidden element</div>
<div class="div3">Element 3 - the one which will slide up and mess with element 2 </div>
```

Comment: But this is not the same as what the OP tried to do: `hide` without arguments performs no animation, while `fadeOut` does. If you use `hide(400)` to mimic the same animation time as `fadeOut` the space issue is coming up again.

Comment: @trincot yeah so OP can use `hide()` instead of `fadeOut(0)` or `fadeOut(0)` itself

Comment: The thing is that `fadeOut(0)` is not what OP is doing. OP uses `fadeOut()` which is equivalent to `fadeOut(400)`. So we should assume OP *wants* an animation of 400ms for the fading out, while `hide()` is immediate.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

I have created jsfiddle which demonstrates the exact requirement. I am hoping this will help:
https://jsfiddle.net/c817r1pt/28/

**Original answer below:**

The problem is fadeOut will add `display:none;` to the element which will cause it to remove from document flow and therefore none of the styles will work on it. As a result elements below it will slide up. The trick is the element should stay there invisible (not removed). Here's a simple solution for the same where I am using `opacity:0;` to hide the element:

**Note:** I have used CSS transition to create fade in - fade out effect.

```js
$(function () {
  $('button').on('click', function () {
    $('.div1,.div2').toggleClass('transp');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
}

div.transp {
  opacity: 0;
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1 transp">This is first div</div>
<div class="div2">This is second div</div>
<div class="div3">This div is always visible</div>

<button type="button">Toggle div1 and div2</div>
```

Comment: But now there is extra white space. I don't think that is the intention of the OP.

Comment: Well it was to demonstrate that the always visible div stays at it's place. I believe what's intended here is he wants to replace one field with another and implement a fade-in fade-out effect without the map to slide up. It can be achieved by overlapping the two elements ".div1" and ".div2"

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle of a simple and clean solution to toggle transitions between two divs. Hope this will help https://jsfiddle.net/c817r1pt/28/